# RxJS and async - Understand the execution flow

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs

I really want to understand the async with RxJS; I wrote this example to see how async function calls work inside RxJS observables; the result is:
func1 --- 10
func1 --- 20
func1 --- 40
func1 --- 30
switchMap ---1--- -->item: 0
switchMap ---1--- -->item: 1
switchMap ---1--- -->item: 2
switchMap ---1--- -->item: 3
switchMap ---1--- -->item: 4
switchMap ---1--- -->item: 5
switchMap ---1--- -->item: 6
switchMap ---1--- -->item: 7
***END***
switchMap ---2--- -->item: 1
switchMap ---3--- -->item: 0.111
switchMap ---3--- -->item: 1.111
switchMap ---3--- -->item: 2.111
switchMap ---3--- -->item: 3.111
switchMap ---3--- -->item: 4.111
switchMap ---3--- -->item: 5.111
switchMap ---3--- -->item: 6.111
switchMap ---3--- -->item: 7.111
switchMap ---3--- -->item: 8.111
switchMap ---3--- -->item: 9.111
MERGEMAP: item-->1000
MERGEMAP: item-->2000
N E X T --> 1000
N E X T --> 2000
MERGEMAP: item-->3000
MERGEMAP: item-->4000
N E X T --> 3000
N E X T --> 4000
MERGEMAP: item-->5000
N E X T --> 5000
C O M P L E T E
I don't understand why func1 --- 40 occurs befor func1 --- 30 and why ***END*** is printed in the middle of switchMap ---1--- and switchMap ---2---
Thanks.

```
import { bufferCount, from, mergeMap, Observable, switchMap } from "rxjs";

module async1 {
  async function func1() {
    console.log("func1 --- 10");
    const loop0 = async () => {
      return from([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);
    };

    const loop1 = async () => {
      return 1;
    };

    const loop2 = async () => {
      const arrayLoop2 = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arrayLoop2.push(i + 0.111);
      }
      return arrayLoop2;
    };

    const loop3 = async () => {
      const arrayLoop3 = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000];
      return from(arrayLoop3);
    };

    let myObservable: Observable<number>;

    console.log("func1 --- 20");
    loop0().then((value) => {
      myObservable = value;
      const myPipeline = myObservable!.pipe(
        switchMap((item) => {
          console.log(`switchMap ---1--- -->item: ${item}`);
          const loop1Result = from(loop1());
          return loop1Result;
        }),
        switchMap((item) => {
          console.log(`switchMap ---2--- -->item: ${item}`);
          const loop2Result = loop2();
          return loop2Result;
        }),
        switchMap((items) => {
          items.forEach((item) => {
            console.log(`switchMap ---3--- -->item: ${item}`);
          });
          const loop3Result = loop3();
          return loop3Result;
        }),
        switchMap((item) => {
          return item;
        }),
        bufferCount(2),
        mergeMap((items) => {
          items.forEach((item) => {
            console.log(`MERGEMAP: item-->${item}`);
          });
          return items;
        }, 3)
      );

      console.log("func1 --- 30");

      const mySubscription = myPipeline.subscribe({
        next: (item) => {
          console.log(`N E X T --> ${item}`);
        },
        error: () => {
          console.log(`E R R O R`);
        },
        complete: () => {
          console.log(`C O M P L E T E`);
          mySubscription.unsubscribe();
        },
      });
    });
    console.log("func1 --- 40");
    return true;
  }

  func1().then((resolve) => {
    console.log("***END***");
  });
}
```

Comment: I dunno, why do you want to know, how exactly are `async` functions handled by *RxJS*. I guess it isn't something complicated, just executing of 'async` delegates. The keypoint is, that waiting for completion of `async function` doesn't block/freeze your application. Order of completed `async` functions depends on, what function completed first, so your emulation doesn't make sense, since you receive results of functions immediately.

Comment: But I'm awaiting the func1() with then() and then print END, or not? Is it wrong?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Using `then(...)` doesn't guarantee that code inside it will have been completed before func1() will end it's work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have control, when code related to observables will be executed, so if you want to be sure that entire logic inside `func1()` will be completed before calling next `function`, you shouldn't use observables and subscriptions inside `func1()`. You should use `Promise<Type>` combined with `await` instead. Then you can call `func1` like that:

```
await func1();
```

If you want to execute functions `console.log("func1 --- 40")` and `console.log("***END***")` after *RxJS* work, you should add them in body of `complete`:

```
        complete: () => {
          console.log("func1 --- 40")
          console.log(`C O M P L E T E`);
          console.log("***END***")
          mySubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
```

Comment: I'm confused. Is the content of .then () not executed after the promise is settled?

Comment: It is, but you don't know, *when* will it be settled. Therefore let imagine situation that promise hadn't been resolved yet (for example you wait for some backend data), but `func1()` managed to finish execution already. I hope you understand.